# New VM can't use unassigned Static Internal IP GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The guide [Reserving a static internal IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#creating_a_vm_instance_with_a_specific_internal_ip_address) includes instructions for reserving a new static internal IP address and assigning the address when creating the VM.

##### Here is a static internal IP address in us-central1 on the `default` network and `default` subnet:

[image]

##### This is how I assign the new Static Internal IP to a new vm:

[image]

##### Somehow, my Static Internal IP is in use by another resource.

[image: Assigning a new vm fails]

The `In Use By` column of my Static Internal IP shows `None`. Is it possible that this refers only to a subset of GCP resources? Is there a cool-down period between IP reservation and assignment?

#### The plot thickens

When I promote the Internal IP address of an existing vm, I learn that the `Specified IP address is not allocated to the project or does not belong to the specified scope.`
This must be a scope or subnet issue. I'll keep poking.

[image: Promoting an allocated Internal IP address on an existing vm]

Comment: Scope in this context means DHCP scope. DHCP scope means a range of IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have the VPC network and the IP address in the same `us-central1` data-center. All I can tell is that the first one screenshot is that it doesn't have any VPC assigned. Disabling DHCP on the default network might cause issues, when spinning up new containers without an IP address.